# How can I connect this LED

Tags: led, circuit-design

I have this IR LED

[image]

IR LEDs emit when forward biased right? And we all know that the longer leg is positive.

When I forward-bias this LED it acts as an open circuit. And it emits when reverse biased!

Would you please help me sorting this out? If you want further explanation please let me know.

Comment: Datasheet please.

Comment: I guess someone in your lab is playing tricks on you. Either he cut the long leg or told you that it's not what it actually is. Led emitts photons when electrons flow (current flows, bias is forward) and excite semiconductor's atoms.

Comment: Clearly the longer leg is not positive.

Comment: Long leg is not always positive. I have a set of red leds which have the anode on the short side.

Comment: @passerby We can also know the negative leg from the cut of the LED. The cut is on the same side of the shorter leg.

Comment: @bort I got no datasheet for this item.

Comment: There are 2 plates inside the LED and usually the bigger one is the negative. Is there any special cases where this is not true?

Comment: another trick that I always stick to (for through hole leds): the funnel shape within the LED is cathode (negative)

Comment: Don't assume that the cut is on the positive side either. Just saying.

Comment: @Passerby I have also had LEDs that are totally backwards.

Comment: My 1st order to a major customer had reversed leads. It was also my last order. Then I quit/retired and went on my own and did it right. That was 12 yrs ago and shipped  > 1m of the best 5mm LEDs in the world.

Comment: If a supplier send me leds with the short lead as anode, I'll never order from them anymore and I'll probably throw all these leds to the dustbin. I have no time checking every led with a magnifyiing glass to find out the connections. Poeple  should use standard signs.

Comment: Alternative solution: re-cut the leads so that the short is - and the long is +.

Comment: As far as LED polarity convention/identification, see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/311389/led-anvil-and-post-are-reversed

Comment: @Fredled It was my oversight on the order, I just assumed the package was standard.  Client did not want to change assembly instructions and retrain workers and was pissed off with all the rework.  10% of 20k pcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply it is backwards from how standard LEDs are configured.

Usually the long leg is the anode and the leg that connects to the bigger metal object inside the plastic case is the cathode, but that is not always the case.

For example:

You'll have to trust me that the leg with the resistor soldered to it was shorter than the other one, but the LED only illuminates when the longer lead is connected to battery negative.

[image]

Comment: No; the issue with this picture is that the anode (+) is on the reflective cup instead of the wirebond (see answer above by Tony Stewart) contradicting Tony's explanation.

Comment: Yes this is what I am talking about. Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of this LED

Comment: @Majid_L - No idea, it came in a random assortment of loose parts.

Comment: @Fredled - I don't understand your objection or I am missing something. The actual anode being on the cup is exactly the cause of OP's problem. Its physical terminations are backwards of the prevailing convention, leading to an incorrect assumption in how it should be connected.

Comment: Look at the LED through transparency on this picture and then look at the other LED in Tony Stewert's answer. Clearly something wierd. Probably two different constructs.

Answer (score 1):

Modern LEDs have a transparent substrate so much of the optical energy reflected from the parabolic reflector and then the distance from the 5mm lens determines the angle of the beam.

The cathode is always the substrate, so this is handy to know when both leads are cut short and may have no flat edge on case. ( also cathode mark)

### So remember this.

The gold wirebond goes to the center of the Anode (+)
The reflector cup is always the Cathode (-)
[image]

I also added some other interesting factoids to my photo.
More importantly REMEMBER THIS;

### Murphy's Law

**- If anything can be backwards , It will be.**

Always double check the datasheet and if not avail. ( bad choice) when in doubt use the diode test.

- weird example
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am sure the info you have given is right but in my case I still get the LED emit when reverse biased.

Comment: Then explain this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIHus.jpg

Comment: Looks like a home made LED not a commercial one with leadframes

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I assure you it was acquired commercially.

Comment: OK I believe you @vofa but does not look like any of the parts from >100 LED factories I once knew in TW. Now there are thousands in China selling online.  Buy the wafer, chip dicer, molds and wirebonder, then bond and make like cookies.  Did it have a datasheet?

Comment: These are the only ones I've ever found like this, and it was a nightmare to figure it out. They came in a random assortment from Jameco, I think. I'm sure it came from a garbage factory with zero QC, but it still ended up in my hands.

Comment: aha well If you ever need 5mm ~ 16Cd in bulk, I got excess inventory.  Not recommended to stare at them at arms length. Hard on the eyes at 20mA.  Amber in 2 shades ITE Yellow and the other one 592nm, 588nm, etc etc, typ 200/bag